# How do I compile and run a java file from CMD that is dependent on JAR files?

Tags: java, cmd, jar, stanford-nlp

Please bear with me as this is my first post and I am still not very familiar with CMD and and java commands. I have already looked at the 20+ posts about this topic but none seem to have the answer, as I continue to run into errors. Currently I have a some code (TestCoreNLP) that runs in NetBeans. However, when I try to run the program form CMD, no luck.

I have tried running the .JAR using this command:

```
C:\Users\Forrest_Hunter\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ParsingEngine\dist>java -jar ParsingEngine.jar "C:\Users\Forrest_Hunter\Desktop\Summer Project\Unassigned Cases\input.xml"
```

however I get this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP
    at Test.TestCoreNLP.main(TestCoreNLP.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I have also tried to compile the code my code using this command (with success in my compilation):

```
C:\Users\Forrest_Hunter\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ParsingEngine>javac -classpath .;stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar src/Test/TestCoreNLP.java
```

But when I try to then run the code with this command:

```
C:\Users\Forrest_Hunter\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ParsingEngine>java -classpath .;stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar src/Test/TestCoreNLP
```

...I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.Test.TestCoreNLP
```

From my understanding from all the other threads that I have read, I think that there is something wrong with my classpath, and that it doesn't point to the location of the needed JAR files, however I honestly am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can you try to run the class with just the classname TestCoreNLP without the src/Test folder name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to make some presumptions based on your question.

you invoke java command line by supplying the main class file with its complete package structure.

so in your case I presume your package is `Test`, and class file `TestCoreNLP`

you would invoke it as

```java
java Test.TestCoreNLP
```

or in your case

```java
java -classpath .;stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar Test.TestCoreNLP
```

Your classpath definition is fine, 2 things to check.

Your current directory should be the one that contains the directory `Test`, there is a class file `TestCoreNLP.class` in that directory.

If the class is inside the Jar, then make sure that you are just invoking it with the package-name.class-name

Comment: Hi, and Thank you! This seemed to work! I did however have to add the other dependent jar files to the scr folder, which holds the Test folder where my .java file is. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
java -classpath .;stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar src.Test.TestCoreNLP
```

Its only that you should use the complete name with the package.

You must be having `package src.Test;` as the first line in your java file.

Comment: Should I be running this command in the directory where the .class file is? And my first line is package Test.

Comment: No from the same folder you invoked javac command from. `C:\Users\Forrest_Hunter\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ParsingEngine`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the package name is not src.Test; at least, that looks very suspicious. It may be that TestCoreNLP doesn't have a package specified.

Look inside the .JAR and find the class. That should indicate what the package, if any, is.

Comment: I have to agree with what you are saying. Right now the hierarchy of my code is Parsing Engine>Source Packages>Test (This is the package)> TestCoreNLP.java (this is my java file) Any thoughts?